# Cannot modify default IMM password (SIGSEGV signal)

Tags: ipmi, ibm

We cannot modify the default USERID/PASSW0RD on an IMM because when we try it modify the USERID's password with a logged in USERID user (that has the "max" rights) we get this message after clicking on "SAVE" (save the new password..)

```
Could not modify password: *** Provider OSBase_AccountProvider(21770) exiting due to a SIGSEGV signal
```

**Our question:** How can we modify the default password to something else?

UPDATE: by IMM we wanted to mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Remote_Supervisor_Adapter#Integrated_Management_Module_.28IMM.29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: if this problem occurs just create a (temporary) superuser, log in with it, then delete the original superuser (the one that you want to ch. pwd.) then create a new superuser with the same username and the good pwd. Then log in with the newly created user, and delete the temporary one.

This was the only solution to modify the users password... to delete the whole user, then re-create it with a good pwd..

Answer (score 0):

I have never used an IMM, but according to the principle that it's the same as other IPMI systems, and that in turn these are just linux, you've encountered a bug.  Software should not raise SIGSEGV in general; it usually indicates a memory corruption bug.  Update your IMM software (might be called firmware in this case) or call support.

Answer (score 0):

Some of IMM config can be managed from IPMI

Use ipmitool, it can modify users and most network parameters (VLAN/ip/gw but CAN't switch network card mode between dedicated and shared)

```
 # ipmitool user list 1
 ID  Name        Callin  Link Auth  IPMI Msg   Channel Priv Limit
 2   admin            true    false      true       ADMINISTRATOR
 # ipmitool user set password 2 PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 0):

First off I would make sure your IMM/RSA is at the latest firmware version to rule out any bugs. As something seems to be wrong with it as I have never got this message changing the password.

Then I would try a IMM reset from the website, if that still produces an error power down the server and remove the power plugs for 5mins to hard reset it. If that still fails try to reset it to factory settings.

Then if you can't change the default USERID password you can try and create a new admin ID with the password you want then try and change USERID after that or delete the account. If that still fails it could be defective and might need to be replaced.

Answer (score -2):

[image: IBM IMM Password reset remotely]

Here is the steps how to remotely reset the IBM IMM password - http://nuttycloud.com/how-to-remote-ibm-server-imm-console-password-reset-steps/

Comment: You should paste the step there, as in case the remote link got erased later on.

Comment: Posting an image is not good enough. Please write a proper answer outlining the steps as text. We want this stuff to be searchable.